# Distributed Transaction or not

Tags: transactions, transactional, distributed-transactions

I'm implementing code that access a remote SQL Server 2005 database and updates its two tables in a transaction. But I am confused whether it is a distributed transaction or not?

Because by definition, a distributed transaction occurs when we update data on two or more network computer systems. But in my case the code is in single application domain and it access and updates only one durable resource manager. Also I can't say it is a local because the database is remote. Please advice.

Comment: If the transaction only affects **one system** - then it's **NOT** distributed by definition. It might be a *remote* transaction - but not a *distributed* one

Comment: @marc_s you made it quite clear, then there is no role of DTC here, right ?

Comment: right my first comment - does it **really** leave anything unclear? If you have **only one system** - then there ***IS NO DTC INVOLVED***

Answer (score 0):

Distributed transactions are usually when one remote system / DB queries another.

You querying a single remote data source would not normally be distributed.

Do be aware however, that sometimes remote queries don't appear distributed but may be under the hood.

E.g. you query a view on a remote source, and the view queries 1 or more other remote db's. This has caught me out a few times!